# Visual studio does not show objects as added to version control

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, azure-devops, dynamics-365-operations

My objects are all added to Version control, but sometimes '+' sign left to it does not appear. If you go in pending changes I can see they are in VC and if you check-in all are checked-in correctly.
It's just annoys me that plus sign isn't displayed.
What should be solution?

Comment: Are you ensuring that you are connected to your source control? I find it best to set VS to automatically connect to TFS or whatever source control on start up to ensure you never accidentally modify a file outside of source control.

Comment: Hi,
Yes, it's always connected for me too

Comment: Can you show the screen shots with source control explorer and the pending changes window?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? What is the version control you are using (TFVC, Git, etc.)?

Comment: I am getting the same issue on my current project but didn't have this issue in other projects. We only allowed to get latest on two out of four folders under Metadata, not sure if that's the reason.